# Stored Procedure to check leap year when entering the date

Tags: procedure

I want to write a procedure which will check whether entered date is a leap year or not.Kindly help me with this.

Comment: http://sqlservercodebook.blogspot.com/2008/07/sql-server-function-to-determine-leap.html

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

**The following scalar function takes in a year and returns a bit flag indicating whether the passed in year is a leap year or not.**

```
create function dbo.fn_IsLeapYear (@year int)
returns bit
as
begin
return(select case datepart(mm, dateadd(dd, 1, cast((cast(@year as varchar(4)) + '0228') as datetime)))
when 2 then 1
else 0
end)
end
go

Here are a few examples:

select dbo.fn_IsLeapYear(1900) as 'IsLeapYear?'
select dbo.fn_IsLeapYear(2000) as 'IsLeapYear?'
select dbo.fn_IsLeapYear(2007) as 'IsLeapYear?'
select dbo.fn_IsLeapYear(2008) as 'IsLeapYear?'
```

**Explanation:**

*Giving the date as input to  your custom sql function
The function takes in the year, appends '0228' to it (for February 28th) and adds a day.
If the month of the next day is a 2 (as extracted by the DATEPART function), then we're still in February so it must be a leap year! If not, it is not a leap year.*